# Can't find error about playing audio in XNA

Tags: xna

I use this in the beginning of the class:

```
SoundEffect bangSound;
```

And then in the constructor I use this code:

```
bangSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/bang");
```

But I get a red line under the Content, and I can't understand what is wrong? Help is preciated! Thanks!

EDIT: I solved it like this:

```
public Asteroid(ContentManager content, string textureName, Vector2 position)
{
...
LoadContentAudio(content);
....
}
```

With content I can then load the sound like this:

```
    public void LoadContentAudio(ContentManager content)
    {
        bangSound = content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/bang");
    }
```

Comment: Does that class know something about Content class? Is it member of that class? In "default" Content is member of Game object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should load your content in the [LoadContent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.loadcontent.aspx) method. If you don't have this method in your derived game class, create a method that looks like this:

```
public override void LoadContent()
{
    bangSound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/bang");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that your class will need to derive from one of the XNA classes (GameObject or somesuch).  Otherwise as John said above, you'll get errors.

If you simply created a class and added the XNA using statements, that isn't enough, it won't know about the static Content object.